# Can you import Mass Effect 2 PS3 save into Mass Effect 3 if the games are from different regions?

Tags: mass-effect-3, ps3, mass-effect-2, region-lock

Most PS3 game save I tried aren't compatible with different regional versions of the same game, but does Mass Effect 3 allow you to import a Mass Effect 2 save from a different region? For example, if I played Mass Effect 2 off a US disc (Region 1) and start Mass Effect 3 with a UK disc (Region 2), will my old save work?

Answer (score 4):

PS3 games are region free but the game saves [are apparently not](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/ps3-is-the-game-save-region-locked.179913305/). I haven't used any cross-region games on my PS3, so I haven't experienced the particulars.

Someone does suggest a (fairly complex) method of getting around [PS3 save region lock](http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/ps3-is-the-game-save-region-locked.179913305/#post-184523996) though:

> (you need a pen drive, PSP or any other USB mass storage device)
>
> 1. On your old game/PS3, copy the save to the device. (select it, press TRIANGLE and choose Copy. Choose the device)
> 2. Go to a computer and plug the device in.
> 3. Go to My Computer>your device>
> 4. Open the PS3 folder and then open SAVEDATA.
> 5. Copy the folder to Desktop then delete it from device.
> 6. On your new game/PS3, start a new game and save.
> 7. Copy the NEW save to the device. (select it, press TRIANGLE and choose Copy. Choose the device)
> 8. Go to a computer and plug the device.
> 9. Open PS3 folder again and then open SAVEDATA.
> 10. Copy that folder to a new folder in desktop.
> 11. Now, rename the NEW folder so that it has the same name as the old folder.
> 12. Open the NEW folder. Here you should see these files:
>
> PARAM.PFD
>   PARAM.SFO
>   PIC1.PNG
>   ICON0.PNG
>   SAVE.DAT
>
> (if there are more files that's fine. Sometimes PIC1.PNG isn't there, that's fine too.)
>
> 13. Open the OLD folder. You should see the same items.
> 14. THIS IS IMPORTANT: MAKE SURE YOU DO NOT MESS UP. Copy PARAM.PFD and PARAM.SFO from the OLD folder to the NEW folder. If you do it the other way round you'll mess up.
> 15. Delete the saved file from the device. And also delete the OLD folder. Drag the remaining folder into PS3/SAVEDATA/.
> 16. Goto your PS3, select Saved Data Utility, choose your device and find the data. Copy this (TRIANGLE) then you're done. Delete save from device.
>
> Play the game and enjoy. This worked for me -- it should work for you too.

This should work for any PS3 game, ME3 included if ME3 is indeed region locked; and since it's EA, I would go ahead and assume they did as much locking and DRM as feasible.

Comment: This will only work if the save can be copied to the PC at all, I know EA tends to lock their save so you can only copy them to the cloud, although I don't know if that's the case with ME2's save. This will also require I own both region versions of ME2.

Comment: @JohnoBoy I don't think that's the case with any PS3 save, are you sure that's not something they only do with Origin? You should be able to do this if you get the transfer region ME2 save from the internet too. GameFAQs usually has saves for popular regions

Comment: I know Dragon Age's 1 save is copy locked as well as Shadows of the Damned, Alice, Rock Band 1&2 and several others. Not all EA games are like that, but looking over this list you can see it's often the case http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/general-ps3-discussion/62819-ps3ts-official-locked-saved-games-thread.html

Answer (score 0):

This works with only save files that can be copied if you have a stock PS3 firmware.

If you are using custom firmware, you can use a file manager or multiman to copy the GAMEDATA folder to a usb stick and use PS3Tools from aldsotools to hack the save file's region.